# How to set up the link process for linking a native module to React Native?

Tags: react-native

I am referring to the command `react-native link AwesomeLibrary`.

Is there any specific configuration file that applies all the changes in the user's `settings.gradle`, `build.gradle`, `AndroidManifest.xml`, and `MainApplication.java`? Or is this process symbolically automated by npm without any specific configuration by the library provider?

Does anyone know of a resource I can refer to? Ironically as my username suggests, this slice of information is layered underneath a lot of irrelevant use-cases, making it rather difficult to find.

Answer (score 0):

How to link a library with `react-native link` varies based on the library.

Most (reputable) libraries will have instructions on how to use them in your app and will tell you if you need to change any other files in addition to running `npm install <lib>` and possibly `react-native-link`.

An example is [react-native-video](https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-video), where is instructions say to use `react-native link` but also have instructions to change various files if `react-native link` doesn't work correctly.

Comment: Right, I understand that. What I'm asking is how do libraries get their `react-native link` to work as instructed according to its configurations.